# Why does VSCode external links don't open and make firefox crashing

Tags: firefox, visual-studio-code

OS version: Ubuntu 17.10 x64
VSCode version:1.17.2 x64

When I click on a link in VSCode which refer to an internet URL (ex:on welcome page at startup>Help>Introductory videos) it opens 2 "Mozilla Crash Reporter" windows with "Firefox had a problem and crash"

I tried to disable all Add-ons in Firefox and VSCode, but the issue is still there.
I tried to re-install VSCode
I didn't find a way to ask VSCode to use Chrome instead of Firefox...

here is the Modzilla firefox report content:

```
Add-ons: sbv4-gradual-rollout%40mozilla.com:1.0.0,firefox%40getpocket.com:1.0.5,activity-stream%40mozilla.org:0.0.0,clicktoplay-rollout%40mozilla.org:1.4,followonsearch%40mozilla.com:0.9.3,aushelper%40mozilla.org:2.0,onboarding%40mozilla.org:0.1,shield-recipe-client%40mozilla.org:65,e10srollout%40mozilla.org:3.00,formautofill%40mozilla.org:1.0,webcompat%40mozilla.org:1.1,screenshots%40mozilla.org:10.12.0,langpack-en-ZA%40firefox.mozilla.org:56.0,%7B972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd%7D:56.0,langpack-en-GB%40firefox.mozilla.org:56.0,ubufox%40ubuntu.com:3.3
AddonsShouldHaveBlockedE10s: 0
BuildID: 20171003222101
CTPCohort: user-changed-from-test
ContentSandboxCapabilities: 119
ContentSandboxCapable: 1
ContentSandboxLevel: 2
CrashTime: 1510735922
DOMIPCEnabled: 1
E10SCohort: addons-set50allmpc-test
EMCheckCompatibility: true
Email: -----@gmail.com
FramePoisonBase: 9223372036600930304
FramePoisonSize: 4096
InstallTime: 1509968396
Notes: Ubuntu 17.10FP(D00-L1000-W00000000-T000) OpenGL: X.Org -- Gallium 0.4 on AMD RS880 (DRM 2.50.0 / 4.13.0-16-generic, LLVM 4.0.0) -- 3.0 Mesa 17.0.7 -- texture_from_pixmap
WR? WR- 
ProductID: {ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}
ProductName: Firefox
ReleaseChannel: release
SafeMode: 0
SecondsSinceLastCrash: 302
StackTraces: 
StartupCrash: 0
StartupTime: 1510735920
TelemetryEnvironment: {"build":{"applicationId":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","applicationName":"Firefox","architecture":"x86-64","buildId":"20171003222101","version":"56.0","vendor":"Mozilla","platformVersion":"56.0","xpcomAbi":"x86_64-gcc3","hotfixVersion":null},"partner":{"distributionId":null,"distributionVersion":null,"partnerId":null,"distributor":null,"distributorChannel":null,"partnerNames":[]},"system":{"memoryMB":7727,"virtualMaxMB":null,"cpu":{"count":4,"cores":4,"vendor":"AuthenticAMD","family":16,"model":5,"stepping":3,"l2cacheKB":512,"l3cacheKB":512,"speedMHz":3100,"extensions":["hasMMX","hasSSE","hasSSE2","hasSSE3"]},"os":{"name":"Linux","version":"4.13.0-16-generic","locale":"en-US"},"hdd":{"profile":{"model":null,"revision":null},"binary":{"model":null,"revision":null},"system":{"model":null,"revision":null}},"gfx":{"D2DEnabled":null,"DWriteEnabled":null,"ContentBackend":"Skia","adapters":[{"description":"X.Org -- Gallium 0.4 on AMD RS880 (DRM 2.50.0 / 4.13.0-16-generic, LLVM 4.0.0)","vendorID":"X.Org","deviceID":"Gallium 0.4 on AMD RS880 (DRM 2.50.0 / 4.13.0-16-generic, LLVM 4.0.0)","subsysID":null,"RAM":null,"driver":null,"driverVersion":"3.0 Mesa 17.0.7","driverDate":null,"GPUActive":true}],"monitors":[],"features":{"compositor":"none","gpuProcess":{"status":"unused"}}}},"settings":{"blocklistEnabled":true,"e10sEnabled":true,"e10sMultiProcesses":1,"e10sCohort":"addons-set50allmpc-test","telemetryEnabled":false,"locale":"en-US","update":{"channel":"release","enabled":true,"autoDownload":true},"userPrefs":{"browser.cache.disk.capacity":358400,"browser.newtabpage.enhanced":true},"sandbox":{"effectiveContentProcessLevel":2},"addonCompatibilityCheckEnabled":true,"isDefaultBrowser":null},"profile":{},"experiments":{"clicktoplay-rollout":{"branch":"user-changed-from-test"},"e10sCohort":{"branch":"addons-set50allmpc-test"}}}
Theme: classic/1.0
ThreadIdNameMapping: 13144:"Gecko_IOThread",13145:"Timer",13146:"Link Monitor",13147:"Socket Thread",13148:"JS Watchdog",13158:"Hang Monitor",13161:"Cache2 I/O",13162:"GMPThread",13164:"SoftwareVsyncThread",13165:"Compositor",13166:"ImgDecoder #1",13167:"ImgDecoder #2",13168:"ImgDecoder #3",13169:"ImageIO",13170:"SysProxySetting",13171:"ProxyResolution",13172:"DataStorage",13173:"URL Classifier",13174:"DNS Resolver #1",13175:"DataStorage",13176:"DataStorage",13177:"HTML5 Parser",13178:"IPDL Background",13179:"Classifier Update",13182:"DOM Worker",13184:"DOM Worker",13186:"StreamTrans #5",13187:"StreamTrans #6",13188:"StreamTrans #7",13192:"ImageBridgeChild",13194:"ProcessHangMon",
Throttleable: 1
UptimeTS: 1.6526776
Vendor: Mozilla
Version: 56.0
useragent_locale: en-US

This report also contains technical information about the state of the application when it crashed.
```

Answer (score 2):

Follow [this workaround](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/85344#issuecomment-574963645) and it should be fixed:

- Remove and purge the current installation using `sudo apt-get remove code --purge` (or in case of using snap, `snap remove code`).
- Download and install the deb package from https://code.visualstudio.com/download
  `sudo dpkg -i <vscodefile>.deb`

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by setting Chrome as "default browser" on my Ubuntu and then re-install VSCode